# Excel - How to Rank from 1 to 100 Based on Values in More than 100 Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I am trying to figure out how to assign a rank from 1 to 100 in a column that has over 200 cells. I need an Excel formula that will keep the correct 1 to 100 rank even when the order of rows is changed.  The way I manually calculate the rank is shown in the picture below:

[image: Manual 1-100 Rank]

=RANK.EQ and =RANK.AVG rank cells from 1 to however many cells are included in the reference, but I need a 1 to 100 rank.

I have tried using =IF(MAX($K:$K)=K3,100,M2-(100/COUNT($K:$K))) but because M2 is based on a cell rather than the next descending sequential number in column K, when I change the order of the rows, the rank becomes inacurrate.

[image: Formula Rank]

Comment: How rank could be a decimal values? What is your desired result? Your second picture shows you already achieve it.

Comment: The rank has decimals because the total number of cells that I'm ranking is greater than 100, but rank caps at 100.  I achieved it in the second picture, but If I adjust the order of the rows and sort by anything other than column K (Score) the rank becomes inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just use rank.eq or rank.avg and normalise the result to a range of 1-100?

```
=99*(RANK.AVG(A2,A:A,1)-1)/(COUNT(A:A)-1)+1
```

[image]